# Что делают скобки в конце данной записи var t=e[w][N](); язык JavaScript

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

на днях читал исходный код одного приложения и наткнулся на такой любопытный пример `var t=e[w][N]();` пытаюсь выяснить что бы это могло значить, никогда не видел что б так писали после декларации какого то массива, кто знает в чем тут дело и что происходит? давайте подумаем вместе

Comment: вызывают функцию, которая находится на `w` ряде, `N` колонке

Comment: это не декларация массива. Это просто взяли элемент массив

Comment: @entithat, не обязательно массив

Comment: либо объект с ключами, которые равны динамическим значениям переменных `w` и `N`

Comment: @entithat, что такое "динамические ключи"? :)

Answer (score 2):

Скобки запускают функцию.

Вот вероятный аналог происходящего, как написали в комментариях:

```js
var e = [ // Массив массивов функций
    [ ()=>{ return 1 }, ()=>{ return 2 }, ()=>{ return 3 } ],
    [ ()=>{ return 'a' }, ()=>{ return 'b' }, ()=>{ return 'c' } ],
    [ ()=>{ return 500 }, ()=>{ return 600 }, ()=>{ return 700 } ]
];

var w = 2, N = 1;

var t = e[w][N](); // Взятие w-шной ячейки, N-ной ячейки, и запуск функции

console.log(t);
```

Или такой:

```js
var e = { // Объект объектов функций
    a: { x: ()=>{ return 1 }, y: ()=>{ return 2 }, z: ()=>{ return 3 } },
    b: { x: ()=>{ return 'a' }, y: ()=>{ return 'b' }, z: ()=>{ return 'c' } },
    c: { x: ()=>{ return 500 }, y: ()=>{ return 600 }, z: ()=>{ return 700 } }
};

var w = 'c', N = 'z';

var t = e[w][N](); // Взятие w-шного свойства, N-ного свойства, и запуск функции

console.log(t);
```

Comment: :-D так а что скобки-то делают?

Comment: `() => { return 3; }` = `() => 3`.

Comment: @entithat я специально так писал для меньшей криптографичности и растянутости функций на манер "как раньше"

Comment: Ого круто тоесть это массив функций что запускаются все вместе?

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой конструктивный ответ!

Comment: @Vladosononame функции не запускаются все вместе, а только создаются. А запускает их оператор круглые скобки.

Comment: Тоесть цикл делает итерации и с каждой итерацией инициализируется новая функция и тут же запускается подобно этому ()();

Comment: @Vladosononame тут нет циклов. Просто объявляется массив или объект с функциями. Много функций создаётся сразу. А запускается одна из них в конце где круглые скобки после квадратных.

Comment: var t=e[w][N](); на сколько я понял эта строчка что - то вроде хранилища функций в массиве обьектов что вызываются при определенном значении w и N